# Getting error while pip installing tensorflow on Windows

Tags: python, tensorflow, pip

I tried installing tensorflow like this - `pip install tensorflow` but I get this error

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for tensorflow
```

So then, I tried adding in the version as well `pip install tensorflow==2.2` but no luck. I tried version 1.15 as well but I still got the same error.

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow==2.2 (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for tensorflow==2.2
```

As for using the `pip3 install tensorflow`. That didn't work as well, giving the same error.

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for tensorflow
```

OS - Windows 10

Python Version - 3.8.5

Pip is up-to-date

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I installed using `python3 -m pip install --upgrade tensorflow`.

Don't ask me how.